# Parallel implementation of Gauss Elimination with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads, gaussian

I need to implement parallel version of following Gauss elimination algorithm using pthreads.

```
procedure GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION (A, b, y)
begin
    for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop */
    begin
        for j := k + 1 to n − 1 do
            A[k, j] := A[k, j]/A[k, k]; /* Division step */
        y[k] := b[k]/A[k, k];
        A[k, k] := 1;
        for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            for j := k + 1 to n − 1 do
                A[i, j] := A[i, j] − A[i, k] × A[k, j]; /* Elimination step */
            b[i] := b[i] − A[i, k] × y[k];
            A[i, k] := 0;
        endfor; /* Line 9 */
    endfor; /* Line 3 */
end GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION
```

I understand the sequential implementation and pthreads but not getting a single hint on how to construct logic for parallel version of it (Thread work distribution criteria, which loops to parallelize etc). Any clue or starting point would help me to continue.

Comment: Can't you use OpenMP?  Find out yourself how the algorithm works and which dependencies there are in the data.  You can then determine which part of the iterations can be parallelised.  It's uncommon here to expect other people to sort this all out for you.  Start with wikipedia for example.

Comment: This algorithm breaks down if you have as much as a zero on the main diagonal.

Comment: http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch08lev1sec3.html  explains how to perform the algorithm in parallel with 1D and 2D partitioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work for each row in the matrix requires all the previous rows to be finished, so you can't divide up the work that way.

However, within a single row, each column can be processed in parallel (with the caveat that original value of the `k`-th column must be saved and used in the calculation of the other columns).  This corresponds to your `j` values.

I believe you can rearrange the algorithm to make this easier, so that there's only one loop over `j`:

```
procedure GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION (A, b, y)
begin
    for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop */
    begin
        for j := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            A[k, j] := A[k, j]/A[k, k]; /* Division step */
            for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
                A[i, j] := A[i, j] − A[i, k] × A[k, j]; /* Elimination step */
        endfor;
        y[k] := b[k]/A[k, k];
        A[k, k] := 1;
        for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            b[i] := b[i] − A[i, k] × y[k];
            A[i, k] := 0;
        endfor;
    endfor;
end GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION
```

Note that the body of the loop over `j` only accesses values in columns `j` and `k` - this is the loop that can be done in parallel.  You can then further note that the second part of the outer loop does not depend on the first part, so you can break the outer loop into two:

```
procedure GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION (A, b, y)
begin
    for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop */
    begin
        for j := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            A[k, j] := A[k, j]/A[k, k]; /* Division step */
            for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
                A[i, j] := A[i, j] − A[i, k] × A[k, j]; /* Elimination step */
        endfor;
    endfor;

    for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop, second pass */
    begin
        y[k] := b[k]/A[k, k];
        A[k, k] := 1;
        for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            b[i] := b[i] − A[i, k] × y[k];
            A[i, k] := 0;
        endfor;
    endfor;
end GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION
```

You can create threads up front, each one responsible for executing the loop over `j` for a subset of the `j` values from `0` to `n - 1`.  These threads will need a synchronisation barrier after each row is processed, because the results of all columns for the previous row are required to process the next row.  You can use `pthread_barrier_wait()` for this.

You will note that not every column (value of `j`) has equal work.  Column `j` is processed by that loop `j` times (so column 0 executes 0 times, and column `n - 1` executes `n - 1` times).  You will want to assign column numbers to threads so that each thread has as close to equal work to do for each row as possible - this can be done by assigning the columns in round-robin fashion.  Eg. if you have three threads A, B and C and 10 columns from 0 to 9, you would assign them:

```
Thread A: 0, 3, 6, 9
Thread B: 1, 4, 7,
Thread C: 2, 5, 8,
```

The thread function would then look something like:

```
for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop */
begin
    call pthread_barrier_wait(row_barrier);
    for j := k + 1 + thread_number to n − 1 step n_threads do
    begin
        A[k, j] := A[k, j]/A[k, k]; /* Division step */
        for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
            A[i, j] := A[i, j] − A[i, k] × A[k, j]; /* Elimination step */
    endfor;
endfor;

call pthread_barrier_wait(phase1_barrier);
```

and the main function would look something like:

```
procedure GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION (A, b, y)
begin
    call start_threads;
    call pthread_barrier_wait(phase1_barrier);

    for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* Outer loop, second pass */
    begin
        y[k] := b[k]/A[k, k];
        A[k, k] := 1;
        for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do
        begin
            b[i] := b[i] − A[i, k] × y[k];
            A[i, k] := 0;
        endfor;
    endfor;
end GAUSSIAN ELIMINATION
```

Comment: I implemented above algo but its not performing as expected. I performed dry run but unable to locate the flaw in logic. Probably it is in function named as thread_subroutine
The code is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/zus28j07rf4vpfk/testing_gauss_paral.c?dl=0

Can you please help me locating it..

Comment: sorry, now working at : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/riilmbbtr74jwfe/gaussian_para_test_6AUG.c?dl=0

Comment: @user3319128: The `phase1_barrier` needs to be initialized to `CPU_THREADS + 1` because the main thread waits on it too.

Comment: @user3319128: I'm also unclear on why you have the dance with `task_distributor()` and `tnode.cols` - why not just have the loop as `for (j = k+1+(thread_num); j < N; j += CPU_THREADS)` and leave `thread_num` the same?